# Use graphs and standard triangles to evaluate $\sin(\frac{11}{6}\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Use graphs and standard triangles to evaluate $\sin(\frac{11}{6}\pi)$.

I end up with $\sin(\pi + \frac{5}{6}\pi)$ which I can't use standard triangles on.

Comment: What are "standard triangles"? And, can you use $\sin (\pi + x) = -\sin x$?

Comment: Standard triangles - the tool where there are two triangles, one with angles of Pi/6 and Pi/3, sides 1,2 and square root of 3. The other with 2 angles Pi/4 and sides 1, 1 and square root of 2. I've never heard of sin(π+x)=−sinx, is that a rule of some sort?

Comment: Okay, so what about the other question, can you use $\sin (\pi+x) = -\sin x$, or, even better $\sin (2\pi - x) = -\sin x$?

Comment: Yeah I can, but then I have -sin(5Pi/6) which I don't know what to do with. All the questions I have had previously ended up either sin(Pi/4), sin(Pi/3) or sin(Pi/6) which I can work out using the standard triangles. Eg. sin(Pi/4) = 1/√2

Comment: What is $2\pi - \frac{11\pi}{6}$?

Comment: 2π−11π/6 = 12Pi/6 - 11Pi/6 = Pi/6. Okay so that works, but where did the 2Pi come from?

Comment: It's the angle of the full circle.

Comment: Oh so 2Pi is a full circle so of course the y value will be the same, that makes sense. Will that method always put a value into a standard triangle angle format?

Comment: No, only if it basically already is. $x \mapsto 2\pi - x$ corresponds to a reflection, so it doesn't change anything fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try $\sin\left(2\pi-\dfrac\pi6\right)$ instead.

To be more explicit: $\dfrac{11\pi}{6}=2\pi-\dfrac\pi6$ and $\sin(2\pi-x)=-\sin(x)$.

Comment: Do you mean sin(2Pi - 11Pi/6)?

Comment: @user88720: What I mean is that $\frac{11\pi}{6}=2\pi-\frac\pi6$

Comment: I'm just not sure how you got that, that's all. I understand that you can add or subtract 2Pi because it is a full period and the y value will be exactly the same, but how did you end up with the Pi/6?

Comment: @user88720: not sure how I got what? I am suggesting two things: $\frac{11\pi}{6}=2\pi-\frac\pi6$ and $\sin(2\pi-x)=-\sin(x)$? Which is it that you are having trouble with?

Comment: They both confuse me because I don't understand how you got there. How is 11π/6 = 2π − π/6 ? As in what steps did you take to arrive at that i.e If a question said prove 11π/6 = 2π − π/6, how would you show your working out?

Comment: @user88720: [Distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property): $2\pi-\frac\pi6=\left(2-\frac16\right)\pi=\frac{11}{6}\pi$

Comment: @user88720: [Sine of a difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities): $\sin(2\pi-x)=\sin(2\pi)\cos(x)-\cos(2\pi)\sin(x)=-\sin(x)$ since $\sin(2\pi)=0$ and $\cos(2\pi)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't know exactly what you mean by "standard triangles", but I feel this can help you (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions)):

[image: Unit circle angles]

If you still don't understand, follow my explaination:

$$\sin\left(\frac{11}{6}\pi\right) = \sin\left(2\pi-\frac{1}{6}\pi\right) = -\sin\left(\frac{1}{6}\pi\right)$$

Now can't you imagine what value might $-\sin(\frac{1}{6}\pi)$ be? Don't worry, look at the picture above: do you see that the angle $\frac{\pi}{6} = 30^\circ$? Now draw a triangle right there, with the radius of the circle as one side, the sinus of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ as the other side, and you've already got a triangle since the remaining side is a part of the diameter (it's very simple: can you see it?) Now, the triangle you've just drawn is indeed half an equilateral triangle! So, if the radius of the circle is one, the side corresponding to the sinus of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$ :)

Therefore $$-\sin\left(\frac{1}{6}\pi\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$$ which is your final result.

Comment: I think the explanation you gave is what I am having trouble with. I just don't know the steps you took to go from 11/6Pi to 2Pi - 1/6Pi

Comment: @user88720. $2\pi-(1/6)\pi = \pi(2-(1/6))=\pi((12/6)-(1/6))=(\pi/6)(12-1)$.

Comment: @user88720 Did you know that writing $11/6$ is exactly the same as writing $2-1/6$? So is $11/6\pi$ and $(2-1/6)\pi = 2\pi - 1/6 \pi$. I think before you can even basically understand trigonometry, you should have learnt at least some basic algebra, since everybody here doesn't understand what you say not to understand.